# itoa function does not work for single digit integers

Tags: c, arrays, char, itoa

I have a custom itoa function that works for integers 10 and greater, but for some reason it returns nothing if the integer passed is a single digit. I can't seem to figure out why that is.

When I print the array after it has been reversed by simply accessing `array[0]` and `array[1]`, I see that a null and that single digit is printed fine, but there is some weird trailing character after the single digit. This only happens for single digits.
for example `(blank)7e` or `(blank)4r`

The function:

```
 char* customitoa(int number, char * array, int base){

array[0] = '\0';

    int quotient = number, i = 1;   

/* stores integers as chars into array backwards */ 

    while(quotient != 0){
            int temp, length = 1;
            temp = quotient % base;

            length++;
            array = realloc(array, (length)*sizeof(char));

            if (temp <= 9){
                array[i++] = (char)(((int)'0')+temp);
                } else {
                array[i++] =  (char)(temp + ('A' - 10));
                }
            quotient = quotient / base;

        }

/* reverse array*/ 
int j; int k;
    k = 0;
    j = i - 1;
    char temp;
/* - different swap functions based on odd or even sized integers */
    if( (j%2) == 1){

        while((k <= ((j/2)+1))){ 
            temp = array[k];
            array[k] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
            k = k+1;
            j = j - 1;
            }
        } else {
            while(k <= (((j)/2))){ 
                temp = array[k];
                array[k] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
                k = k+1;
                j = j - 1;
            }
        }

    return array;
    }
```

The function is called in this context:

```
char *array;
array = malloc(length*sizeof(char));

array = myitoa(number, array, base);

printf("%s", array);

free(array);
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: The reversal code should be the same for odd and even strings.  If `char *beg` points to the first digit and `char *end` points to the last digit, then `while (beg < end) { char tmp = *beg; *beg++ = *end; *end-- = tmp; }` should do the trick.  Or, if `int i = 0;` is the index of the first digit and `int k` contains the index of the last digit, then `while (i < k) { char tmp = array[i]; array[i++] = array[k]; array[k--] = tmp; }` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(quotient != 0){
    int temp, length = 1;
```

length is always 1 in this loop.

change to

```
int length = 1;
while(quotient != 0){
    int temp;
```

realloc is performed once at the end

```
array = realloc(array, (length)*sizeof(char));
```

move outside while loop

```
}//while end
array = realloc(array, (length)*sizeof(char));
```

The following conditions is incorrect

```
while((k <= ((j/2)+1))){ 
....
while(k <= (((j)/2))){
```

change to

```
int L = j/2;
...
while(k <= L){ 
...
while(k <= L-1){
```

To summarize in one

```
if( j%2 == 1)
    L=j/2;
else
    L=j/2-1;
while(k <= L){ 
    temp = array[k];
    array[k] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
    k = k+1;
    j = j - 1;
}
```